# Track dirty for not-persisted attribute in an ActiveRecord object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I have an object that inherits from ActiveRecord, yet it has an attribute that is not persisted in the DB, like:

```
 class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :bar
 end
```

I would like to be able to track changes to 'bar', with methods like 'bar_changed?', as provided by ActiveModel Dirty. The problem is that when I try to implement Dirty on this object, as described in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), I'm getting an error as both ActiveRecord and ActiveModel have defined `define_attribute_methods`, but with different number of parameters, so I'm getting an error when trying to invoke `define_attribute_methods [:bar]`.

I have tried aliasing `define_attribute_methods` before including `ActiveModel::Dirty`, but with no luck: I get a not defined method error.

Any ideas on how to deal with this? Of course I could write the required methods manually, but I was wondering if it was possible to do using Rails modules, by extending ActiveModel functionality to attributes not handled by ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm using the `attribute_will_change!` method and things seem to be working fine.

It's a private method defined in `active_model/dirty.rb`, but ActiveRecord mixes it in all models.

This is what I ended up implementing in my model class:

```rb
def bar
  @bar ||= init_bar
end
def bar=(value)
  attribute_will_change!('bar') if bar != value
  @bar = value
end
def bar_changed?
  changed.include?('bar')
end
```

The `init_bar` method is just used to initialise the attribute. You may or may not need it.

I didn't need to specify any other method (such as `define_attribute_methods`) or include any modules.
You do have to reimplement some of the methods yourself, but at least the behaviour will be mostly consistent with ActiveModel.

I admit I haven't tested it thoroughly yet, but so far I've encountered no issues.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the `init_bar` method is just used to initialise the attribute. If you need some initialisation logic you'll have to define it, otherwise you can just ignore it.

Comment: Oh it's a method that I have to define... it's not a built in method right?

Comment: Correct. You have to define it if you need an initialiser.

Answer (score 3):

`ActiveRecord` has the `#attribute` method ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb#L194-L202)) which once invoked from your class will let `ActiveModel::Dirty` to create methods such as `bar_was`, `bar_changed?`, and [many others](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Thus you would have to call `attribute :bar` within any class that extends from `ActiveRecord` (or `ApplicationRecord` for most recent versions of Rails) in order to create those helper methods upon `bar`.

Edit: Note that this approach should not be mixed with `attr_accessor :bar`

Edit 2: Another note is that unpersisted attributes defined with `attribute` (eg `attribute :bar, :string`) will be blown away on save. If you need attrs to hang around after save (as I did), you actually can (carefully) mix with `attr_reader`, like so:

```rb
attr_reader :bar
attribute :bar, :string

def bar=(val)
  super
  @bar = val
end
```

Comment: This seemed promising however it did not work for me. I do not believe the `attribute` method defines modifier methods which implement the `ActiveModel::Dirty` interface

Comment: I take it all back. As long as you _only_ add `attribute :bar, :string` (do not mix with `attr_accessor :bar` or defining custom setter), this works great and would be my preferred approach... when SO unlocks my vote I will upvote

Comment: actually I realized it _is_ possible (and for me was necessary) to mix with `attr_accessor`, because unpersisted `attribute :bar` gets blown away on save, and I needed it in a callback.... I guess I'll edit again 

Comment: Or I'm not sure -- does it merit a followup answer?

Comment: I think the path you took (i.e., editing the answer by adding additional info) was the right one. Thanks once again @steve 

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution that worked for me...

Save this file as `lib/active_record/nonpersisted_attribute_methods.rb`: https://gist.github.com/4600209

Then you can do something like this:

```
require 'active_record/nonpersisted_attribute_methods'
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::NonPersistedAttributeMethods
  define_nonpersisted_attribute_methods [:bar]
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = 3
foo.bar_changed? # => true
foo.bar_was # => nil
foo.bar_change # => [nil, 3]
foo.changes[:bar] # => [nil, 3]
```

However, it looks like we get a warning when we do it this way:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `bar'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc.
```

So I don't know if this approach will break or be harder in Rails 4...

Comment: This is the only answer the really addresses the question, but there has to be a way to do this without deprecation warnings.

Anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 0):

Write the bar= method yourself and use an instance variable to track changes.

```
def bar=(value)
  @bar_changed = true
  @bar = value
end

def bar_changed?
  if @bar_changed
    @bar_changed = false
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that is what I ended up doing, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it using ActiveModel methods.

Comment: its simple enough to do with basic ruby, i think using ActiveModel for this is extreme overkill. If this is part of a bigger picture relavent to ActiveModel, you can make table-less models (see http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) and could use similar technique for table-less attributes, but again would be overkill for such a simple task... keeping it simple is best

Comment: Reusing ActiveModel::Dirty and ActiveModel::AttributeMethods (which are *already* included into ActiveRecord::Base) *WOULD* keep it simple, if only that were possible. I don't think that reusing methods (from a class's ancestors) is overkill at all. And I blame ActiveRecord for overriding define_attribute_methods such that you can't reuse the define_attribute_methods method from ActiveModel::AttributeMethods. Why does it have to be so difficult to have a mix of both persisted and non-persisted attributes in a model?

Comment: This approach might work in some cases, but one thing it *doesn't* do that ActiveModel::Dirty would do for you is include this change in the hash returned by the `changes` method.