# Track model changes on virtual attributes with previous_changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I'm tracking changes on my model and I would like to track changes on a has_many relation. The model has:

```
define_attribute_method :tag_tokens
attr_reader :tag_tokens

def tag_tokens=(ids)
  tag_tokens_will_change! unless ids == @tag_tokens
  self.tag_ids = ids.split(",")
end
```

Combination of http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

The result is this exception which is caused on the `define_attribute_method` line. I believe this method is required to create the `tag_tokens_will_change` method.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194@mm/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:59:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?': undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error, and it turns out the documentation we were referring to is outdated.

The current way to trigger this change is to call `attribute_will_change! :attr_name`

See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666745/track-dirty-for-not-persisted-attribute-in-an-activerecord-object-in-rails) for more details.